# Best practices for an effective use of Coq's hint database

Tags: coq

"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."

Well, I know that, but still it feels worth asking here.

---

I've been told many times that I should use the hint database and auto because it's the best thing ever and whatnot. However, the few times I tried to use that, I have been utterly annoyed by trivial details. Here is one thing that keeps happening.

```
Section Annoying.

Variable T : Type.
Variable P : T -> Prop.

Axiom notP : forall x, ~ P x.
Hint Resolve notP.

Goal forall (x : T), P x -> False.
intros x.
auto. (* nothing... *)
replace (P x -> False) with (~ P x) by reflexivity.
(* fold not. does not work, don't know why either but that is not the point here... *)
auto.
Qed.

End Annoying.
```

---

Therefore, my question is: how do people use the hint database and not run into such trouble. Are there goods rules of thumbs for an effective hint database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

auto works by applying unmodified theorems to goals.  It looks for what theorems to apply by a syntactic observation of their shape.  So you theorem notP will only apply to goals of the form

~ P ...

A goal of the form P x -> False is not in this form syntactically.  In fact, the auto tactic works in the following manner: first use intros as much as possible, then try to apply theorems.  So you goal is transformed into

```
H : P x
=========
 False
```

and then it tries to apply theorems that can prove False.  Unfortunately, it tries only to apply theorems for which there is no guessing of instantiations needed (theorems that can be used with the tactic apply and do not require the "with" extension).  So a theorem with a statement of the form
"forall a, P a -> False" would never be used by auto, because apply would complain that it does know how to instantiate a.

So, good candidate proofs for auto are proofs that you can do by only using intros and apply, with no instance of unfold or apply ... with and no manual application of theorems to arguments, and where at each step, the rightmost formula (at the end of arrows) of the theorem uses the predicate as the predicate appearing in the goal's conclusion.

Your annoying example works because the goal at some point the main formula is "~ P x", so the main symbol is not, and auto has the lemma notP in its table for this main symbol.

Here is an example that works well:

```
Variable my_le : nat -> nat -> Prop.

Hypotheses my_le_n : forall x, my_le x x.

Hypothesis my_le_S : forall x y, my_le x y -> my_le x (S y).

Hint Resolve my_le_n my_le_S.

Lemma toto : my_le 10 14.
Proof.
auto.
Qed.
```

After the Hint command, auto has the two lemmas "my_le_n" and "my_le_S" in its table, to be used when the goals main symbol is my_le.  When looking at "my_le 10 14", it tries these two lemmas in turn.  The first fails, but the second one apply and produces a new goal "my_le 10 13", this can be repeated several times until auto manages to apply "my_le_n".  So auto explores a tree of possibilities where the branching comes from the fact that there may be several theorems applicable for a given goal.  Also, the length of the branches is limited to 5, so that my_le 10 15 will not be solved by auto.  You can change the length of branches by giving a numeric argument to auto.  so "auto 20" will solve "my_le 10 15" and other similar instances.

Comment: I will take this as an answer even if I knew most of it. I just wondered whether people expanded definitions of `not` in lemmas that would go into the hintdb, so that they would work whenever some tactic turned `not`s into `-> False`s... I guess not, so it's slightly irritating.